# Probability Question Find probability who wins.

Tags: probability

Suppose that there are ten cards numbered from 1 to 10. The cards are shuffled and the game is played between two players: player 1 and player 2. Player 1 starts the game. Player 1 wins if he selects any card numbered from 1 to 4 both inclusive and the game ends. If player 1 fails to draw the card with desired number, then player 2 draws a card and he wins if any card numbered from 5 to 10 is drawn. If player 2 fails to draw the desired card the game goes back to player 1 and he draws the card again. The players keep on playing the game until one of the player wins. Find the probability that player 1 wins the game.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: When, if ever, are drawn cards returned?